# Screen Sharing changes resolution for no reason

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, resolution, screen-sharing

I'm using the built-in Screen Sharing client in macOS to connect to a Mac Mini 2020 M1 by running `Connect to Server` in Finder and choosing the `vnc://machine-name.local` link.

The connection works fine, except for one thing: It keeps changing resolution approximately every 10 seconds. The effect is that what is shown in the client window changes between the whole screen and a fraction of the screen.

If I open the Displays setting through VNC it just shows the ordinary settings for the ordinary display. I can set it to `Scaled` and specify a certain resolution, but that does not help.

The Screen Sharing Preferences has a few options that seem related to the display, e.g. `Show full size` and `Show the screen at full quality`. I have changed them in all combinations that I can think of. Nothing has made any difference.

There is also the `Scaling` toggle in the toolbar of the Screen Sharing app. Again, it doesn't seem to do anything (what is it supposed to do?).

I have also tested connecting with the RealVNC `vnc-viewer`, it had the same issue.

The Mac mini is not really headless, it does have a monitor connected to HDMI, but the monitor is mostly turned off.

Comment: I just earned the necessary reputation to post everywhere so I'm copying this comment here: "Show the screen at full quality" is for screens of computers you’ve never connected to before, so take View > Full Quality

Comment: "flashing between Retina and not, i.e. it toggles between fuzzy and sharp". This could also be related to Wi-Fi bandwidth fluctuation. Check your signal with some good tool like [WiFi Signal](https://www.intuitibits.com/products/wifisignal/)

Answer (score 1):

I lack the necessary reputation to add a comment, so please bare with me if I add it here.

I believe that setting a specific display resolution beforehand (e.g. 2560 x 1440) is important for its stability during the connection.

When you clicked `Scaled` did you get additional resolutions by pressing and holding down the `Option` key or was it one of the four recommended resolutions, scaling from Larger Text to More Space?

Otherwise, I'd recommend installing [Display Menu](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) or [EasyRes](https://apps.apple.com/app/easyres/id688211836) (both Free on Mac App Store) to set that resolution.

If none of these work, other Screen Sharing protocols such as [Apple Remote Desktop](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375?mt=12) (pretty expensive) or the two solutions from [Astropad](https://astropad.com) (Luna Display and Astropad itself in Mac-to-Mac Mode) might work better.

More often than not your Mac Mini will be running Headless or the plugged screen will be turned off. An inexpensive solution would be an HDMI Dummy Plug (an adapter designed to plug into the HDMI port of your Mac). [Newertech](https://www.newertech.com/products/hdmi_headless_video_adapter.php), for example, has one of these at a very affordable price (they had one at under $15, but I can't seem to find the link right now). This will allow you to have a display emulator with a reliable preset resolution.

Comment: Yes, I've tested the additional resolutions you get by `Option`-clicking

Comment: How would I set "a specific display resolution beforehand"? I can't find such an preference in `Screen Sharing`

Comment: May I ask which resolution you selected through `Option`-clicking and is it sticking during the session?

Comment: Also, is your Mac Mini running Headless?

Comment: I just added a new section about HDMI Dummy Plug adapters to have a display emulator with a reliable preset resolution.

Comment: Is it running headless: Good question. I'll amend my question, but to answer directly: It is connected to a monitor, but that monitor is not currently used.

Comment: If the monitor is turned off, you can't count on it. It is running headless and you'll probably need a dongle (see the new section I added to my answer).

Comment: Hmm, ok, some progress: If I explicitly choose 1920x1080 (my standard resolution) either using Scaled or EasyRes, it does seem to stay on that resolution. The problem now is that it is still flashing between Retina and not, i.e. it toggles between fuzzy and sharp.

Comment: Glad to hear that. At least your resolution is sticking. Let me now think about a solution for your Retina display.

Comment: One easy solution that comes to mind is to force Retina display through [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/). I stopped using it because it required SIP to be disabled. They have a 10-day free trial if you want to try.

Comment: Under Screen Sharing > Preferences did you try "Show the screen at full quality" or View > Full Quality?

Comment: "Show the screen at full quality" is for screens of computers you’ve never connected to before, so take the second one: View > Full Quality

Comment: Yes, I have both "Display/Show full size" and "Quality/Show the screen at full quality (more detailed)" set

Comment: Then I'm afraid, after you have tried everything, you're left with either the NewerTech HDMI Headless Video Accelerator or SwitchResX as a solution for Retina display. At least you now have the appropriate resolution.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Tried SwitchResX and the sharp/fuzzy toggle continues, even after choosing resolution in that app.

Comment: This could also be related to Wi-Fi bandwidth fluctuation. Check your signal with some good tool like [WiFi Signal](https://www.intuitibits.com/products/wifisignal/)

Comment: Both computers are connected with gigabit ethernet cables on the same LAN, no wifi, so bandwidth is excellent. I've confirmed the bandwidth with benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

#### Check the display settings on the Mac Mini

- Open `System Preferences` and:
- Change the display resolution to "Standard"
- Switch any enhancement like `True Tone` etc off.
- Check the color profile and change it to default if necessary.

#### Check Energy Saver on the Mini

- Go to `System Preferences` and head to `Energy Saver`
- Search for `Automatic Graphics Switching` option and untick it. (That option is not available on Mac Airs)

#### Restart the Mini in safe mode

- Restart your Mac by pressing and holding the power button and shift the key

#### Reset NVRAM (or PRAM)

- Restart your Mac by pressing and holding `Option+Command+O+R` simultaneously for a few seconds

#### New User

- Create a new user on the Mac Mini (no kidding)

Comment: I can't find any preference named `Automatic Graphics Switching` (or even `Graphics`). This is a Mac mini, always connected to power.

Comment: I don't have any enhancements in Display (My monitor is connected through a sony receiver to a 1920x1080 projector). I tested changing the color profile. Did not help.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn What about the other solutions?